# How to stub method in initialize with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

```
class Party
    attr_accessor :number
  include Validations

    def initialize
        self.number = proccess_args(2)
        puts luhn?
    end

    def proccess_args(opt)
        ARGV[opt].downcase
    end
end
```

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe Party do
  before :each do

    new_method = Party.method(:new)
    allow(self).to receive(proccess_args).with(2).and_return('add')
    @party = Party.new 
  end
end
```

spec_helper.rb
    require_relative '../'

```
require 'yaml'
```

How can I use rspec, to ensure proccess_args is not actually called, but is simulated in order to avoid ARGV from blowing up my tests? For example I would like to fake the call of proccess_args(2) to return "Jason Wade", and avoid ARGV[opt] from ever being touched by rspec.

Comment: showing you spec file would help here a lot

Comment: I've included the test

Answer (score 0):

`allow(ARGV).to receive(:downcase).and_return('whatever')`

You are telling RSpec to `allow` `ARGV` to `receive` a method called `:downcase` `and_return` `'whatever'` instead of actually calling it in the code being tested. (That part may not be particularly useful, but it's the sort of explanation that got it to click in my head.)

Comment: Can you try that, it seems to not work, and fail in proccess_args :(

Comment: Edit the original post to add the code for your test file. The line I posted is JUST the stub itself, not a test.

Comment: Done, I'm just trying to build that object to write tests.

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.1.3p242 and   rspec (3.2.0)

Comment: and this still fails, I am not sure why.

Comment: What does the output say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79458/discussion-between-spectre6000-and-jason-wade).

Comment: `receive` and `have_received` take symbols as arguments if I recall correctly.